# How do I delay the launchImage display time

Tags: ios, swift3

How do I delay the launchImage display time in swift 3?
Or, how do I insert a delay method into function Application(_ application: ..?) to make it return after several second?

Comment: Please be more precise (what do you want to delay? The time it appears, dissapears? ...)  and show what you have tried (code).

Comment: that is a really wrong idea

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this. If you do not respond to events (for example, by delaying returning), the OS can and often will kill the application.

If your point is to have a "splash screen," first, please don't. They're user-hostile. That said....

The way you do this is to put up a full-screen image view in your root view controller that duplicates your launch image. Using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter`, schedule to remove the view after whatever delay you want. You can even fade it this way if you like. Similarly, if you want to display it periodically when the user comes back to the app, you can put that in `applicationWillEnterForeground` or similar places. (Remember, the launch screen is only shown when the program is *launched*, which is very unpredictable. Usually apps are just put in the background.)

Please don't do this; it's horrible UX. But that's how you do it (and I've done all of these things).

Comment: @RobNapier I thought killing the developer was a bit harsh :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewController & use it as LaunchScreen.Present & dismiss whenever you want in appDelegate methods.

> Note Delaying launch image it gives bad impression to your app takes a
>   lot longer

Answer (score 0):

Design a  new viewcontroller and set that as initial viewcontroller(in interface builder) and can segue to another view controller in button click or can use timer and move to another view controller. Or use delay function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let delay2 = 2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time2 = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay2))
    dispatch_after(time2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("HomePage", sender: self)
    })
}
```